# How to quickly locate a file named "666.mp3" with keyboard in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

If you start typing in an Explorer window without focusing on a text box, Explorer will move the highlight to the file with a matching prefix name. I rely on this very much as it does not require me to reach my mouse to locate files from a long list.

Now I have a folder with 1,000 files, named from `000.mp3` to `999.mp3`. When I hit numpad 6 three times in quick succession, instead of focusing on `666.mp3`, Explorer is locating `602.mp3` for me, which comes quite unexpected.

I can see the details as I hit every key:

- Hit `6` after idle: Focus on `600.mp3`
- Hit `6` again: Focus on `601.mp3` (was expecting `660.mp3`)
- Hit `6` again: Focus on `602.mp3` (was expecting `666.mp3`)
- Hit `6` again: Focus on `603.mp3` (was expecting an "asterisk" sound for an invalid prefix)

It seems like I'll have to hit `6` 67 times just to locate `666.mp3`, which completely defeats the purpose of using this method in the first place. Is it possible to do it this way efficiently?

Comment: It may not answer actual question, but this is why I switched to 'Everything' for finding stuff.

Comment: Windows has since always behaved this way - it only positions using the first letter, and successively typing the same letter moves to the next occurrence. Windows has never behaved in the way you describe. Are you sure you have not been using for that some third-party product?

Comment: Sure you don't want a Mac? ;)) It's been able to do this for *decades*. Windows still can't. You're going to need some 3rd party Explorer mod for this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Actually I never ran into this situation with so much stupidly-named files. Previously I've only played with alphabet-named files where I'd never encounter something like `aaa.doc`, so I never had the chance to discover this behavior.

Comment: It probably has to do with the keyboard key delay. You can adjust it in Control Panel. Works as you expect on my machine, as in if I type the name of the file (without stopping or much delay), it finds the file you are looking for (i.e. 666) . If I delay typing, it makes the jump around the next file (i.e. 602).

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran I'm hitting the key as quickly as possible, like <200ms between each stroke. Never touched relevant settings so they should be default.

Answer (score 2):

In **Explorer**, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> puts the focus on the Search box. So

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>

  -or-
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>

shoud do thee trick!